# How can I make notepad printto not print binary under Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-printer

The following command works fine for the default printer on Windows Server 2008.

```
notepad.exe /p "filename"
```

However, it does not work properly when I modify it for a network printer, like this:

```
notepad.exe /pt "filename" "Printername"
```

It does not fail entirely, but it performs binary printing, not proper printing. The same command does work on my Windows XP machine.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a driver interpretation issue.  Have you installed this printer on the server first?  I know it's a network printer but if the driver isn't loaded then it won't have the proper files to communicate properly.

Comment: yes. the driver has been added and printer is working fine notepad.exe /p "filename" is working fine.